# where to find good review resources?

Tags: self-learning, online-resources

I am taking my certification test for secondary mathematics next month and I am extremely overwhelmed by the amount of stuff i need to brush up on.

http://www.mttc.nesinc.com/PDFs/MI_field022_SG.pdf

that is  the review guide containing information on everything we will be tested on. Does anyone have suggestions for places I can go to easily look up everything from unit conversions to differentials..

Any resource with good information is helpful. Also and recommendations for things i need to remember to brush up on. It's been over a year since I took calc 3 and a lot longer since I took anything else.

Comment: currently im trying to brush up on the properties of fields rings groups and vector spaces